# Share rich media content to Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are building a site with HTML5 and three.js viewer for 360 images just like 
https://sketchfab.com/models/raZtEDFsTw6QF0gYv23zAijY6qI

when I share my page to facebook timeline , it don't show the rich content inside the timeline when i hit play button. we am using same https://sketchfab.com/models/raZtEDFsTw6QF0gYv23zAijY6qI
and youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsUEk6CPAGg

I believe Facebook had made custom setup for sketchfab.com and youtube.com to show and share rich media in their timeline .

how can we request Facebook to allow us do the same ?

our example : http://www.vrcommerce.co/vrc/ 
when you share this link in Facebook timeline , it appear as video , but when you click play , it failed to render content as sketchfab and youtube

any help will be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: We are just testing HTML5 with a few partners. So for now you need to use flash

Comment: Thank you @WizKid for quick response .
when you say flash 
should i use 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
as hack and keep the actual content as HTML5 , or should i convert everything to flash ? 


Also , can we be part of these few partner companies to test our feature with Facebook sharing ? what is the requirement for this ?

Comment: @WizKid can you please help us on above to get answers . Thanks for your help

Comment: We are just testing with a few and not accepting more. You need to convert everything to flash